# How to scrape a log-in protected website using username, password and token?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

First of all I'm a python beginner and this my first trial to scrape websites

I'm trying to scrape a website and I found my way using the cookies, but the cookies seems to expire every 30 minute, so I tried to log in using username, password and cookies but I'm not able to get there

The code I'm trying with

```
response = requests.get('https://aff.ven-door.com/login')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
token = soup.find('input', {'name':'_token'})['value']

payload = {
    'token' : token,
    'username' : 'mail',
    'password' : 'pass'
}
with requests.session() as s:
    s.post(login_url, data=payload)
    logged_in = s.get('https://aff.ven-door.com/products')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(logged_in.content, 'html.parser')
```

I doubted that I created the payload dictionary the wrong way, so I tried getting the tokens at the top of the payload and another trial with it as the last key value pair but it didn't work

Also tried to change the username key to name as it is in the page source so it is

```
{'token' : 'actual token',
'name' : 'actual login':
'password': actual password}
```

But also didn't work

Tried to replace the key of the token to be either  '_token' or 'csrf-token' to match the page source with no luck -actually I don't know what I'm doing-

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but can't figure what it is

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do this using only requests/beautifulsoup by sending the credentials in the payload. It depends on how the site has set up its authentication so it might challenging.

One option is to do the scraping using Selenium instead (python library).

Selenium opens an actual browser that is controlled by python. You can then find the input fields and type the credentials there and then click the submit button. from there you can continue scraping as normal by getting the cookies from the selenium browsers logged in session and using that.

This will be slower than finding a way to do it with only requests/beautifulsoup.